# How to remove all linked stylesheets but keep one by ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove all linked stylesheets in the head , while keeping one of them.

I want them all removed , except for the one with id=custom_stylesheet

```
<link type="text/css" href="" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link type="text/css" href="" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link type="text/css" href="" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link id="skin_stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link id="custom_stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

This worked to remove them all , but how do i edit it to keep one ?

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not` or `.not()`:

```
$('link[rel=stylesheet]:not(#custom_stylesheet)').remove();
$('link[rel=stylesheet]').not('#custom_stylesheet').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [*document.styleSheets* collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-DocumentStyle-styleSheets) that contains all the style sheet for a document. The advantage is that it includes **all** style sheets, i.e. those added by *link* elements and *style* elements.

So iterate over that:

```
var sheet, sheets = document.styleSheets;

for (var i=0, iLen=sheets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  sheet = sheets[i];

  if (sheet.id != 'custom_stylesheet') {
    sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet);
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's a jQuery–ised version that uses *each*, something like:

```
jQuery.each(document.styleSheets, function(i, sheet) {
  if (sheet.id != 'custom_sytleSheet') $(sheet).remove();

  // or much more efficient
  // if (sheet.id != 'custom_sytleSheet') sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
 $('link[rel=stylesheet]').filter(function(){
    return  this.id !="custom_stylesheet";
 }).remove();
```